# Understanding the ambiguous calls in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I tried to understand the ambiguous calls in below code, but i am not able to get it.
Three of them give an error.

```
struct A {
    virtual void func(int a, float b) const { std::cout << "a1" << std::endl; }
    virtual void func(double a, float b) { std::cout << "a2" << std::endl; }
    void func(unsigned int a, char b) { std::cout << "a3" << std::endl; }
};


int main() {
    A baseObj;
    baseObj.func(1, 1.0);//Error : expecting a1
    baseObj.func(2, 2.0f);//Error : expecting a1
    baseObj.func(3, 'c');//Error : expecting a3

    return 0;
}
```

if I change it to:

```
    baseObj.func(1.0, 1.0);//a2
    baseObj.func(2.0, 2.0f);//a2
    baseObj.func(3, 'c');//Error, if i remove unsigned from function, then it gives a3. 

// I dont know what exactly happening here
```

Can someone explain how to figure out the ambiguous call?

thanks

Comment: You should read about [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) and how overload candidates are ranked. There is no exact match for any of the 3 calls, so the compiler has to find next best match and in each case there is more than one candidate with the same rank, so it doesn't know which one you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone has pointed it out in the now deleted answer, MSVC has the most eloquent explanation:

```
<source>(13): error C2666: 'A::func': overloaded functions have similar conversions
<source>(7): note: could be 'void A::func(unsigned int,char)'
<source>(6): note: or       'void A::func(double,float)'
<source>(5): note: or       'void A::func(int,float) const'
<source>(13): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int, double)'
<source>(14): error C2666: 'A::func': overloaded functions have similar conversions
<source>(7): note: could be 'void A::func(unsigned int,char)'
<source>(6): note: or       'void A::func(double,float)'
<source>(5): note: or       'void A::func(int,float) const'
<source>(14): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int, float)'
<source>(14): note: note: qualification adjustment (const/volatile) may be causing the ambiguity
<source>(15): error C2666: 'A::func': overloaded functions have similar conversions
<source>(7): note: could be 'void A::func(unsigned int,char)'
<source>(6): note: or       'void A::func(double,float)'
<source>(5): note: or       'void A::func(int,float) const'
<source>(15): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int, char)'
```

You can see it for yourself here: https://godbolt.org/z/ee4E61d79

Now, why is that?

In the first call you are passing an `int` (`1`) and a `double` (`1.0`) and expecting `a1` to be called. However, `a1` requires a const object (due to the `const` qualifier), an `int` and a `float`.

So, there are two conversions that have to happen: `baseObj` has to be "converted" from `A` to `const A` and `1.0` has to be converted from `double` to `float`. Likewise, `a2` requires 2 conversions -- `1` to `double` and `1.0` to `float`. Same with `a3` -- `1` to `unsigned int` and `1.0` to `char`.

In the eyes of the compiler all 3 candidates are equivalent, as they all require conversions. So, it doesn't know which one it should call and gives an error.

Similar things happen in the second and third calls.

---

UPDATE in response to the comments.

Overload ranking is a fairly complicated process covered in [over.ics.rank](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank). In an attempt to keep my answer simple -- and in the hopes that no one will notice ;), I've oversimplified things a bit.

But, without spending hours digging through the standard, this is what's happening as far as I can tell:

[Section 4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#4) says that conversion sequences are ordered by their rank. In the 3rd call all 3 candidates have the same rank -- Conversion, because they all require a conversion.

NB: `int` -> `unsigned int` is a conversion and not a promotion.

[Section 3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#3.2) defines when one conversion sequence is considered better than the other. And sequences of the same rank are considered indistinguishable (neither is better) regardless of the number of conversions.

So, that's why the 3rd (as well as the first two) calls fail.

Comment: Can you explain why #3 fails? I only see one conversion required to call the `a3` overload: the conversion from `int` to `unsigned int`.

Comment: Thank you for the ans. But i still did not follow. I actually saw this and tried to understand it. but its kinda confusing. Maybe you can explain it in detail (last one especially). Would be really helpful

Comment: @Coder: "*But i still did not follow.*" What didn't you follow? Do you not see where the conversions are coming from? Outside of case #3, this answer seems to explain things adequately.

Comment: *"all 3 candidates are equivalent, as they all require 2 conversions"* Nitpick: They are not ranked by the number of conversions. For one overload to be better than the other, it has to, roughly speaking, be at least as good as the other in every aspect (if an overload needs a conversion for i-th parameter, it can never be better than one that doesn't), and then better in at least one aspect.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right. I've added an update to the answer to correct that number of conversions doesn't matter.